# Can I change the clock on the 6th gen Nano to digital instead of analog?

Tags: ipod-nano

[Everyone wants a iPod Nano watch, right?](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1104350651/tiktok-lunatik-multi-touch-watch-kits?ref=popular)  All the videos I see are on an analog clock (you know, the one with hands.)

Can you change the clock to digital, rather than analog?

Comment: Try getting your hands on a display model at the store and fiddle with the settings? I'm waiting until I see an actual "iWatch" product myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 6th gen Nano can now be [updated with a software update](https://gigaom.com/2011/10/04/2010-ipod-nano-gets-new-features-via-software-update/) which introduced the features from the 7th gen, including 16 watch faces, some of which are digital.

> Version 1.2 of the iPod nano software brings improved fitness features (which are better able to detect and track walking or running work outs), as well as the new single icon scrolling interface, which replaces the 4×4 icon grid. You can switch back to small icons or turn off home screen items altogether from the Settings menu.
>
> Last but not least, you’ll get access to all the new iPod nano clock face options.

Answer (score 1):

Digital clock is sadly not available as an option in the Clock app for the iPod nano. All you can change is the theme to black or white.

The only digital clock available on the iPod nano is the one in the top bar when navigating through the device.

http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/iPod_nano_6thgen_User_Guide.pdf

Cheers.

Comment: Now that the 7th generation nanos are out, the 6th gen nanos get a software upgrade that features several digital clocks.

Answer (score 0):

The iPod nano only can change the clock face from black to white. If you don't believe me, check if there is any option in the settings that says you're allowed to change your clock faces from the one you have now to a totally different one.

Comment: If you apply the software update for the nano from iTunes, you'll get the variety of clock faces available on the new one. See several of the other answers for confirmation.